# Replacement for ^M when scripting with Vim

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I am creating a script that grabs all links from a web page's source code. I would like to call Vim from a bash script and the easiest way for me to do that is to use a vim script.

I have a file called 'script.vim':

```
:g!/https:\/\//d
:%norm!/https^Mdi"Vp
:wq!
```

I am deleting every line without https and the norm command is being used to remove all text that is not inside double quotes & containing https.

Everything works except the ^M and I'm not sure how to go about replacing that in the script file.

For extra info, I'm calling the script file like so: `vim websitecode.txt -s script.vim`
Simply put, **I need a replacement for ^M so the norm command will work in a script**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a replacement of:

```
:%norm!/https^Mdi"Vp
```

I would propose you:

```
:exe '%norm!/https' . "\<CR>" . 'di"Vp'
```

The `""` converts escpaped sequence `\<CR>` into `^M`.

Comment: It's working, but oddly enough it seems to only be removing one line at a time. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: My mistake :-| I forgot `%` to range over all the lines ;-)

Comment: Haha I totally wasn't thinking about it either. Thank you so much